# Use redux state in exported function (functional component) React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux, export

I would like to generate an array from my existing redux state with exported function in functional component. I want to use my useSelector data and dispatch function in my exported function. I only need the generate function that I can call from outside, but for using redux state, I have to create a functional component too.

To show you my problem, here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { treeActions } from "../store/treedata-slice";

function GenerateTree() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const pathways = useSelector((state) => state.tree.pathways);
  const pickedRenderElementType = useSelector(
    (state) => state.tree.pickedRenderElementType
  );
  const pickedRenderElementValue = useSelector(
    (state) => state.tree.pickedRenderElementValue
  );
  const scenarios = useSelector((state) => state.tree.scenarios);
  const treeData = useSelector((state) => state.tree.treeData);
  
  return <div></div>;
}

export const generate = () => {
  const arr = scenarios;
  if (pickedRenderElementType === "scen") {
    dispatch(treeActions.setTreeData(/* make the tree */));
  }
  if (pickedRenderElementType === "path") {
    dispatch(treeActions.setTreeData(/* make the tree */));
  }
  if (pickedRenderElementType === "act") {
    dispatch(treeActions.setTreeData(/* make the tree */));
  }
};
export default GenerateTree;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**useSelector** and **dispatch** cannot access outside component function.
Instead, we can pass **dispatch**  and **redux state** as arguments.

Add dispatch to the props of the function and then add it as well when ever you call the function.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { treeActions } from "../store/treedata-slice";

function GenerateTree() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const pathways = useSelector((state) => state.tree.pathways);

  const pickedRenderElementType = useSelector(
    (state) => state.tree.pickedRenderElementType
  );

  const pickedRenderElementValue = useSelector(
    (state) => state.tree.pickedRenderElementValue
  );

  const scenarios = useSelector((state) => state.tree.scenarios);
  const treeData = useSelector((state) => state.tree.treeData);
  
  return <div></div>;
}

export const generate = (dispatch) => {
  const arr = scenarios;

  if (pickedRenderElementType === "scen") {
    dispatch(treeActions.setTreeData(/* make the tree */));
  }

  if (pickedRenderElementType === "path") {
    dispatch(treeActions.setTreeData(/* make the tree */));
  }

  if (pickedRenderElementType === "act") {
    dispatch(treeActions.setTreeData(/* make the tree */));
  }
};

export default GenerateTree;
```

Comment: Can you show me how can you pass dispatch and redux state as an arguments? I tried but it gives me undefined value in the generate function.

Comment: function GenerateTree() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  const pickedRenderElementType = useSelector(
    (state) => state.tree.pickedRenderElementType
  );

  function handler(){
generate(dispatch,state)
}
  return <div></div>;
}

export const generate = (dispatch,state) => {
/*processs*/
};

you can call function from only other component.

Comment: Not working, return undefined values when i console log dispatch or state. I call it from an other component.